# Codeigniter delete last "/" in url

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri

I tried a lot of solutions but nothing works. i'm searching for a good one for my problem: 
In my view i have to put a link like that :

```
<?php $id = 100; ?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url($id); ?>">
   Click
</a>
```

The echo here will show https://www.domain.com/folder/100
,but what i want is that show me https://www.domain.com/folder100

Comment: Is the structure always `...folder/somenumber` or you generally want to remove the last `/` on any case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your base_url like this inside config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://www.domain.com/';
```

Now you can do this this way

```
 site_url('folder'.$id);
```

Or

```
base_url().'folder'.$id;
```

I assume you already have  `$config['index_page'] = '';` at your config.php

Answer (score 0):

`site_url()` splits into segments

So try `$url = site_url() . $id;` it may work.

Comment: No, Already tested and show the same thing because site_url() automatically add / in the end of the url.